# Avoid DeadlineExceeded in BPF tests

Tags: solana-test-validator, test-bpf

It seems that as the number of BPF tests in your program grows, the likelihood of encountering `RpcError(DeadlineExceeded)` errors increases as well. While using the `warp_to_slot` function on the BanksClient helps, it is not very intuitive when it is needed.

Are there any guidelines on how to mitigate DeadlineExceeded errors?

Example: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/actions/runs/5696435013/job/15441607791

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can absolutely happen, typically because of a race condition when freezing the bank and trying to process a transaction on it.

In the meantime, I've had a lot of success by just refreshing the blockhash periodically, ie. https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/11fe168871508f81e1de425377eafffb094e07c9/stake-pool/program/tests/withdraw.rs#L635-L639

And there's even this function directly on `ProgramTestContext` that you can use https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/f4504d055a159097b0716e65df24646fff5f6d13/program-test/src/lib.rs#L1210

Note that it should be fixed with https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/31637, but if you're still seeing problems feel free to file an issue!